# Responsive grid in ionic2/Angular2

Tags: angular, ionic2

I want to display a fixed number of cards in each row for specific screen size,
such as: 4 cards in large screen,2 cards in medium screen, 1 card in small screen.
I tried the **responsive-sm , responsive-md , responsive-lg** like so

```
    <ion-row responsive-lg>
       <ion-col *ngFor="let item of items" width-25 showWhen="tablet">
          <ion-card>...</ion-card>
       </ion-col>

       <ion-col *ngFor="let item of items" width-50 showWhen="phablet">
          <ion-card>...</ion-card>
       </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
```

but, no luck.
**PS:** I am trying to mimic a flow layout behaviour.

Answer (score 0):

It was pretty simple actually :P,

```
    <ion-row wrap>
      <ion-col *ngFor="let item of items">
       <ion-card>...</ion-card>
     </ion-col>
   </ion-row>
```

Just don't use the **width-x** nor the **responsive-xx**, and instead specify a max-width and min-width for the ion-card.